# Android App Locking Camera

Tags: android, android-camera

Is it possible to get the android app (process ID or package name or whatever) of the app/process that is currently locking the camera on an Android device?  It's easy enough to see if it's locked using `Camera.open()` - but I want to find out the process which has it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CameraService is responsible for locking the camera device. This isn't a part of the NDK and hence not accessible through your app. See this [related discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/Z1j4OIG6uUw/eUTnW33ar2UJ).

You may have to use some non-standard way, like gaining root privileges, and then interacting with the underlying Android system directly.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but I figured that I might have missed it somewhere...