# How to know which app(process) is using camera in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android App Locking Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095203/android-app-locking-camera)

It's possible to check whether camera is being used. But can we further get information on which app is using it?

Comment: Yes, and I'm sorry I did not find that question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no standard API to do this. You're gonna need root privileges to try something like that. You can check CyanogenMod's  implementation of the service that controls this here:

[CameraService.cpp](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/services/camera/libcameraservice/CameraService.cpp)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure it out.